# Extracting metadata object from MediaElement (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, metadata, mediaelement

I am attempting to retrieve metadata from a URLResource. The URLResource is not controlled by me, but passed into a function that I am using.

The URLResource is created like this:

```
var resource:URLResource = new URLResource("http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/osmf/content/test/logo_animated.flv");

// Add Metadata for the URLResource
var VideoParams:Object = {
Name:"Logo Video",
Owner:"Self",
Duration:"1:25:20",
category:"education"
}

resource.addMetadataValue("VideoParams", VideoParams);
var media:MediaElement = factory.createMediaElement(resource);
```

Now the URLResource contains the metadata. I will recieve a MediaElement resource. How do I extract the metadata back?

Here's what the debugger shows (media is a MediaElement object containing the URLResource w/ metadata) :

```
fdb>print media.resource.
$1 = [Object 246396705, class='org.osmf.media::URLResource']
_mediaType = null
_metadata = [Object 416970209, class='flash.utils::Dictionary']
_mimeType = null
url = "http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/osmf/content/test/logo_animated.flv"
fdb>print media.resource._metadata.
$2 = metadata = [Object 416970209, class='flash.utils::Dictionary']
VideoParams = [Object 416970305, class='Object']
(fdb)print media.resource._metadata.VideoParams.
$3 = VideoParams = [Object 416970305, class='Object']
category = "education"
Duration = "1:25:20"
Owner = "Self"
Name = "Logo Video"
```

I've attempted extracting the metadata object with:

```
media.resource.getMetadata("VideoParams");
```

and a host of other attempts, but can't figure out how to get at that darned metadata.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turned out to be pretty easy...just needed to use the getMetadataValue function in the URLResource object like this:

```
var temp:Object = media.resource.getMetadataValue("VideoParams");
trace('Owner:', temp.Owner);
```